# Почему не работает webdriver manager?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я решил использовать webdriver для своего скрипта на python, но почему-то он выдаёт ошибку которая представлена ниже. Почему может быть подобное и как это решить? Заранее спасибо за помощь!!!

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Could not get version for chromium with the any command: reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome" /v version
Current chromium version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN chromium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 416, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)`
```

Comment: Легкая проблема, вы просто не установили веб драйвер для хрома. Или он его не находит или версия не та

Comment: Но webdriver_manager должен сам эту версию подтягивать, но почему-то это не делает

Comment: Хмм, попробуйте подстроиться под программу а не чтоби программа подстроилась под вами :)

Comment: Could not get version for chromium "Не возможно получить версию веб драйвера для хрома" или по простому "веб драйвер не обнаружен" в чём проблема то?

Comment: Да, но почему невозможно? Ведь к примеру на другом ноутбуке прекрасно подтягивает, а на моём - нет

Answer (score 0):

Выставите переменную окружения

```
os.env['WDM_SSL_VERIFY'] = 0
```

Перед вызовом кода webdriver-manager

p.s. на момент ответа актуальная версия 3.8.0